# Not able to add data to room database in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to learn the room database. First I was just downloading the data from firebase and passing it to the recycler view and it was working perfectly now I am trying to download all the data into the room from firebase and observe it from the room to avoid the time lag it takes to download data from firebase. First I want to read data from the local DB and then update it from the firebase. Currently, it is returning null for postListRoom.

MyCode

> Repositery

```
     private val postList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Post>> = MutableLiveData()
        //    private val postListRoom: MutableLiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>> = MutableLiveData()
        private val postListRoom: MutableList<PostRoomEntity>?=null
    
       fun loadDataPost() {
    
            var postsDao:PostsDao?=null
    
            val list2 = mutableListOf<PostRoomEntity>()
            db.collection("Posts")
                .addSnapshotListener { snapshots, e ->
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(myTAG, "listen:error", e)
                        return@addSnapshotListener
                    }
    
                    for (dc in snapshots!!.documentChanges) {
                        when (dc.type) {
    
                            DocumentChange.Type.ADDED ->{
                                dc.document.toObject(PostRoomEntity::class.java).let {
                                    list2.add(it)
                                    postListRoom?.add(it)
                                    Log.d(myTAG, " postList Room is"+postListRoom?.size)
                                }
    //                            postListRoom?.addAll(list2)
    //                            Log.d(myTAG, " id = $list2")
                                if (postListRoom != null) {
                                    postsDao?.insertPost(postListRoom)
                                }else{
                                    Log.d(myTAG, " postList Room is null ")
                                }
    //                            val postRoom:PostsDao
    //                            postRoom.insertPost(postListEntity)
                            }
                            DocumentChange.Type.MODIFIED ->{
    
                            }
                            DocumentChange.Type.REMOVED ->{
                                Log.d(myTAG, "Removed city: ${dc.document.data}")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    
        }

  @JvmName("getPostList")
    fun getPostList(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>? {
        var postsDao:PostsDao?=null
       return postsDao?.getPosts()
//        return postList
    }
```

> Entity

```
@Entity
@Parcelize
data class PostRoomEntity(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    val postId:String=""
    ,val userId: String=""
    ,val name: String=""
    ,val timestamp: String=""
    ,val likes: String=""
    ,var favourites: String=""
    ,val description: String=""
    ,val color: String=""
    ,val username: String=""
    ,val userimage: String =""
    ,val image_count: Int = 0
    ,val image_url_0: String=""
    ,val image_url_1: String=""
    ,val image_url_2: String=""
    ,val image_url_3: String=""
    ,val image_url_4: String=""
    ,val image_url_5: String=""
    ,val image_url_6: String=""
):Parcelable
```

> Dao

```
@Dao
interface PostsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertPost(PostEntity: MutableList<PostRoomEntity>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAllPosts(PostEntity :List<PostRoomEntity>)

    @Query("Select * from PostRoomEntity")
    fun getPosts(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<PostRoomEntity>>

//    @Query("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id= :id")
//    open fun getNoteById(id: Int): NoteEntity?
}
```

> Database

```
@Database(entities = [PostRoomEntity::class], version = 1)
//@TypeConverters(DateConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun notesDao(): PostsDao?

    companion object {
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "notesdatabase.db"

        @Volatile
        var instance: AppDatabase? = null
        private val LOCK = Any()
        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase? {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(LOCK) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.applicationContext,
                            AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME
                        ).build()
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Append the code where you have added data from firebase to Room database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any mistake in your code. One thing you should try is to try clearing app data and then start the app. My reasoning is that the local firebase cache has all the data already that is on your firestore due to which add document change is not called and nothing is inserted in your sqlite database. Clearing data will help clearing everything and you may see the result you desire.

Edit:- The problem is you are not initialising `postListRoom` to a list and using it with its value as null. If you do

```
private val postListRoom: MutableList<PostRoomEntity>?= mutableListOf()
```

It will still create problem since you will be adding a single entry multiple times based on your code. To prevent that you will require to clear your list everytime you call `postsDao?.insertPost(postListRoom)` which essentially defeats the purpose of using the list in the first place. So my advice would be

1. Either to use some delay to insert the list to database after some time has passed and clear the list everytime it is successfully inserted
2. Use a threshold of list that will insert the entries into database after n entries are inside the list. There is a chance that some entries may get lost if the threshold is not reached and user kills the app
3. Do not use the list at all and directly insert the entry as soon as it is recieved.

Comment: actually, the problem is I am not able to add data into the room the condition where I am checking (postListRoom != null) postListRoom is actually returning null

Comment: Just one more thing I wanted to ask how to do I get context into the repository to instantiate the DB because it needs context

Comment: Use it like [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-get-application-context-from-anywhere-example/)

Comment: Please accept if it answers your question